# Get App Crashes from Xcode stuck at Downloading App Records

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to get the crash logs from Xcode Organizer/Crashes but it gets stuck at
"Downloading App Records..." (I let it try to download for about 1/2 day)

[image]

Did you encounter this issue and manage to fix it?
I use Xcode 8.2

Thank you!

Comment: same issue. Any idea?

Comment: @Saranjith I removed everything from Library/Developer/Xcode/Products and it worked on my side